# How do I trim out parts of a string to get my required information?

Tags: c#, json

I want to display each of these in a textbox:

```
{"hash": "somehashencryption", "ip": "this.is.the.ip", "maxplayers": 64, "mppass": "3e6876ca64423fc478073f511dc7e11a", "name": "Name of the server", "players": 0, "port": 25565, "uptime": 2050648}
```

In this form:

```
name = Name of the server

ip = this.is.the.ip

mppass = 3e6876ca64423fc478073f511dc7e11a

port = 25565

uptime = 2050648

hash = somehashencryption
```

I'm very basic at coding, I'm trying to turn that into a list, there's an API:

http://www.classicube.net/api/serverlist/

Comment: In which part do you have problem? downloading the json data? parsing it? turning it to a list? displaying in some control? BTW: which UI do you use? Winforms? WPF? WebForms? etc.

Comment: Your input string is a JSON object. Parse it.

Comment: It's JSON. How to deserialize a JSON object in .NET using Json.Net: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about the JSON, thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: I use WinForms btw, I might have a problem turning it into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use NuGet to include JSON.NET in your project.
2. Use http://json2csharp.com/ to convert your sample input into a class like this:

   ```
   public class ServerListItem
   {
       public string hash { get; set; }
       public string ip { get; set; }
       public int maxplayers { get; set; }
       public string mppass { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public int players { get; set; }
       public int port { get; set; }
       public int uptime { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Deserialize and consume the data like this:

   ```
   var s = "{\"hash\": \"somehashencryption\", \"ip\": \"this.is.the.ip\", \"maxplayers\": 64, \"mppass\"" +
       ": \"3e6876ca64423fc478073f511dc7e11a\", \"name\": \"Name of the server\", \"players\": 0" +
       ", \"port\": 25565, \"uptime\": 2050648}";

   var server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerListItem>(s);
   Console.WriteLine("Hash: " + server.hash);
   ```

Comment: The link is different form the json in the question. So more correct version would be:  **3.** you can download the string like this. **4.** Get the list like this **5.** Why am I doing this when there is no search effort in the question